# Casting WebMatrix DynamicRecord or retrieving the underlying IDictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, casting, dynamicobject

this might be an easy one but I am really not getting it.

As far as I understand:
The most `dynamic` types ins C# rely on `IDictionary<string,object>`

I did a spike with WebMatrix.Data and I would like to cast my result to `IDictionary<string,object>` but this does not work...
WebMatrix.Data query returns an `IEnumerable<DynamicRecord>` This is what I try to cast...

here is my naiv code ...

```
var o = (DynamicObject) webmatrixRecord; // No Exception but o is still DynamicRecord

var o = (IDictionary<string,object>) webmatrixRecord; // Runtime Binder Exception

var o = ((IDictionary<string,object>)((DynamicRecord)webmatrixRecord)) // InvalidCastException;
```

So what is a proper way to cast an Dynamic object?

WebMatrix.DynamicRecord: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/webmatrix.data.dynamicrecord(v=vs.111).aspx

Dynamics.DynamicRecord: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The most dynamic types ins C# rely on `IDictionary<string,object>`

Not necessarily. [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) does, but there are plenty of other ways of being dynamic, and [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) doesn't.

Note that reference conversion casting doesn't change the type of an object. So where you've got this line:

```
var o = (DynamicObject) webmatrixRecord;
```

... the type of the *variable* will be `DynamicObject`, but that doesn't change the type of the object that the *value* of `o` refers to.

For your other casts, it seems that it just doesn't implement `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can't cast to it. You could use [`DynamicObject.GetDynamicMemberNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx) to get the dynamic names, and then use [`DynamicObject.TryGetMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx) to get the values. It's not ideal though - I would personally try to avoid even having the requirement, if possible...

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I choosed DynamicObject only because DynamicRecord inherits from it and I thought it brings me closer :-/
I need an ExpandoObject or and IDictionary<string,object> from DynamicRecord... but since u said there is no cast I have to write something...

Comment: @silverfighter: Does `DynamicRecord` itself expose anything? I can't see anything after a quick browse - so you may well need to call `GetDynamicMemberNames` and then `TryGetMember` in order to build your dictionary.

Comment: As far as the open source version von WebMatrix.Data says .. I take your bet with GetDynamicMemberNames and TryGetMember... http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.Data/DynamicRecord.cs